# How to create url with query string with 'Url.Action' correctly so it works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

In razor view `script` a url with a query string is created like this and when clicked on some element `window.location` is set to this url with query string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// ...

var url = "@Url.Action("action", "controller", 
    new
    {
        a = model.a,
        b = model.b,
        c = model.c
    }, null)";

$("#something").on("click", function () {   
    window.location = url;
});

// ...

</script>
```

This works fine in *Internet Explorer 11*, the requested url looks like this:

```
http://localhost/App/Controller/Action?a=True&b=123&c=False
```

But in *Firefox 47.0a2* and *Opera 35.0* the requested url looks like this:

```
http://localhost/App/Controller/Action?a=True&amp;b=123&amp;c=False
```

Notice the `amp;` after each `&` in the query string. This `amp;`s causes the model binding to fail with Firefox and Opera (model is binded without erros in IE 11).

Why is Firefox and Opera behave differently than IE?

---

*The Error looks like this:*

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'a' of
>   non-nullable type 'type' for method 'method' in 'controller'. An optional parameter must be a reference
>   type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parametername: parameters

Comment: Just to add a little detail, window.location is an object not a string, so use Queti's answer but also tweak the JS accordingly: "window.location.href = url;"

Comment: @BryanL read [this](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/windowlocation-vs-windowlocationhref) article.

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't realize that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC will encode the `@Url.Action`. You can simply tell it not to encode using `@Html.Raw(Url.Action())`